# ModuleNotFoundError but module is installed on pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-packaging

I am trying to get familiar with Python through Pycharm but I cannot for the life of me accomplish a step without an error.
I installed packages I need through pip but when I try to import them I receive the error that ends with following line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I ensured from the terminal that I correctly installed the packages. I am suspecting that for some annoying reason the packages are not installed in the paths that Python is not looking at or maybe there is some problem related virtual environments(I have no idea what is it and why do I even need it)?

How can I correct this?

Comment: Pycharm might be using a different python that what you use from the terminal.

Comment: Libraries are installed per Python version (first two numbers). It is possible you are using a different Python version than `pip` installs for. To prevent this try to use `python -m pip install ...` with the same Python version than you are running your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+numpy

Comment: @Daviid  I mean they both use the Python 3.11.5 versions so I am not sure what is going on there.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Python path and install a new version, if needed. You can create as many virtual environments as required. To easily tell them from each other, use different names. PyCharm can create a virtual environment for your project based on the project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the Python version you used to install the package and the version used by Pycharm. Make sure you set the right interpreter and virtual environment on Pycharm.
However, I recommend using Pycharm -instead of the command line- to download packages, as it can detect the base interpreter (which you can set) and virtual environment (which you can build via Pycharm). It can be done with the "Python packages" tool in Pycharm.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I installed the packages from the Python packages tool and it worked. Do I have to install the packages for every new project? Also, I am pretty sure I set the right interpreter, I checked the path of the python.exe and both terminal and pycharm uses Python 3.11.5 so I have no what is going on.

Comment: It depends on what environment you used to install packages. If it is global, you need to set the global interpreter in Pycharm, else set the relative environment (Pipenv, Poetry,...).